# having a trouble setting java_home in ubuntu

Tags: java, react-native

hello am trying to set environment for react native development, i followed all the steps in the get started guide, am trying to run the project on a Genymotion emulator, when i try to start the project i get an error message saying that i didn't set the java_home path, i watched a tutorial on how to do that, i think my problem is that am setting the path wrong... this is the path to java exe files from the tutorials :

```
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "/usr/lib/java/jdk1.7.0_65/bin/java" 1
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javac" "javac" "/usr/lib/java/jdk1.7.0_65/bin/javac" 1
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javaws" "javaws" "/usr/lib/java/jdk1.7.0_65/bin/javaws"
```

the path to those files in my computer is this :

```
/usr/lib/java/jdk-12.0.2_linux-x64_bin/data/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-12.0.2/bin$
```

so am wondering what to change.

[image]..... this is a screenshot of ls "bin" !

Answer (score 0):

To set `JAVA_HOME` environment variable, do the following:

1. Launch Terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard.
2. Enter the following command:
   $ `gksudo gedit /etc/environment`
3. Depending on where you installed your Java, you will need to provide the full path. For this example, I installed Oracle JDK 7 in the `/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle` directory.
   Scroll to the end of the file and enter the following:
   `JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle`
   `export JAVA_HOME`
4. Save your file and exit **gedit**.
5. Lastly, reload the system PATH with the following command:
   $ `. /etc/environment`

The above method will save you the hassle in having to run the commands every time you log in to your computer.